# Viewing the content of a hard drive in binary without using a Hex editor

Tags: hard-drive, text-editors, binary-files, hex-editor

Can we view the content of a hard drive in binary without using a Hex editor but with a simple text editor like Mousepad or gedit ? I'm using Debian.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by content of hard drive? Files? Boot sectors? MBR?

Files can be viewed in hex form in CudaText editor. Open CudaText, call it’s Command Palette, find item “open file in viewer, hex”. This allows to open any binary files. Hex or text form can be changed via pop up menu of statusbar field.

Answer (score 1):

What about **mcedit** from Midnight Commander?